# Warum ist das Prefix eines trennbares Verbes nicht am Satzende?

Tags: sentence-structure, separable-verb

Warum ist im folgenden Satz, der heute in einer Zeitung geschrieben wurde, *mit* nicht am Ende des Satzes? Ich denke, dass der Autor das Verb **mitreißen** hier benützt.

> "Mit Ja haben gestimmt 605 Genossinnen und Genossen", rief die Frau im knallroten Blazer den jubelnden Berliner Parteitagsdelegierten zu. **Und riss die Arme gleich selbst *mit* in die Luft.**

Answer (score 4):

Nein, *mit* bedeutet hier *zusammen mit den Delegierten*. Man reißt die Arme *in die Luft*, nicht *in die Luft mit*.